# can I ask about how to repair a gaming device

Tags: discussion, scope

I have a gaming device I want to ask about repairing and want to make sure I can ask it here

Comment: Repair questions are off-topic unfortunately.

Comment: ok that is why I was asking I was unsure and saw the tag

Comment: This particular question would belong on meta.EE.SE. Repair questions are off-topic unless a detailed understanding of the electronics is shown.

Comment: I have one rep I can't put it on meta @Hearth

Comment: I have a 3Ds circle pad that needs replacing and I consider that repairing

Comment: Repair questions are not strictly off topic, you have to "demonstrate a good understanding the underlying design of what is being repaired". Only consumer electronics are mentioned as a reason for not being on topic.

Comment: so as long as I show I understand the inner workings I can ask?

Comment: @Luna, this is becoming silly .... please delete your comments, because they are cluttering up the post ..... then ask your question ..... right now your post is not much different than any off-topic post and you have not even had a chance to ask your real question .... thank you for asking first, it demonstrates that you are being polite

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We discourage broad, open-ended questions relating to the reverse engineering, modification and/or repair of devices here on EE.SE because the answer(s) tend to become long strings of unrelated edits and/or comments. While this might help you with your immediate problems, it is of no value to the site overall. We DO allow certain questions about reverse engineering in which you explain in detail what you know about the circuit and then focus on a few points about which you still have doubts.

Comment: I am not sure I follow

Comment: but thank you for telling me

Comment: ask questions that have simple answers "whai it this part" "how does this circuit work"